# NetVault - how to limit to one job per client?

Tags: netvault

In Quest NetVault, I'm backing up a Linux client. I need to define about five different daily jobs for this one client (the filesystem backup job separate from some database backup jobs). Is it possible to limit the number of jobs concurrently running on a client? For example, if the first job takes more time than usual, the second job waits and doesn't put additional load on the system?

Of course other client machines should be able to run their jobs concurrently with this client (I see the server allows 50 max concurrent jobs and I want to keep that).

Nothing found on Google, nothing catch my eye in the client's "Configure" screen, strange.

Comment: Not knowing net vault but in scheduling a common approach is that completion of one job [triggers another job](http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC127194)